# Why use sql tags in struct in some go libs like gorm?

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

Well I know the necessity of tags in struct in golang and how is it accessed by reflect in golang. But I have searched and could not find a reliable answer to the question of why I should use sql tags in struct while writing struct for sql results. I have explored many sample code and people are using `sql:"index"` in the struct and `sql:"primary_key"` in the struct.

Now I have done indexing in the database layer, isn’t it enough? Should I have to use `sql:"index"` too get the best results? Like so I have defined primary key attribute in the database should I have to specify `sql:"primary_key"` as well?

My code seems to work fine without those. Just want to know their benefit and usages.

Comment: Where are you seeing this sample code?

Comment: Well most of the ORM is using it. All in their own way mainly Gorm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are referring to an ORM library like [gorm](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm)

In that case, metadata like `sql:"primary_key"` or `sql:"index"` will just tell the ORM to create an index while trying to setup the tables or maybe migrate them.

A couple of examples in [gorm](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm) could be: indexes, primary keys, foreign keys, many2many relations or when trying to adapt an exiting schema into your [gorm](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm) models, setting the type explicitly, like for example:

```
type Address struct {
    ID       int
    Address1 string         `sql:"not null;unique"` // Set field as not nullable and unique
    Address2 string         `sql:"type:varchar(100);unique"`
    Post     sql.NullString `sql:"not null"`
}
```

Comment: In addition, for many non-ORM libraries (e.g. [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx)), the struct tags are used to map column names to struct fields - e.g. `EmailAddress` in your source to `email_address` in your DB.

Comment: having issues with auto_increment unique id fields with gorm and default values. plain just dont work on insert of a row.

Comment: Why do you link to some fork instead of https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm? This looks fishy.

Comment: @TheDiveO Thanks for commenting on this. I'm updating the links.  As context for the random reader who may be reading this:  Before go-gorm migrated to it's own repository, it was hosted under Jinzhu's organization. Jinzhu is the original author behind go-gorm and several other go libraries like https://github.com/jinzhu/now, https://github.com/jinzhu/copier, https://github.com/jinzhu/configor, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the package you are using and your use-case. Is it enough for CRUD? Almost always, unless the package says so which is often rare but possible. Few packages sometime do under the hood magic which may give rise to bugs. If you are aware of these behaviours, or are quite explicit in your code, you'll probably avoid it.

Indexing tags mostly allows you to use package's migration tools translating your model declaration into sql queries (`CREATE` statements). So if you always want to do this by yourself, then you probably needn't bother adding such tags.

But you may find yourself a bug if your package requires a tag. For example, in case of `gorm`, the `Model` method takes a struct pointer as an input. If this struct has a field named `ID` it uses it as a primary key, that is, say `ID` has a value of "4", it will add a `WHERE id=4` automatically. In case your struct has `ID`, you needn't even add a `primary_key` tag and it will still be treated as one. This behaviour may cause issues when you have both a "non-primary-key" `ID` field, and another field which you are actually using as the primary key. Another example for `gorm` is [this](https://v1.gorm.io/docs/create.html#Default-Values). A possible behaviour can also be checking for nullable property and throwing an error if an `INSERT` statement involves a `NOT NULL` field getting a `NULL` value.

On a different note, adding tags to your structs can be considered good practice since it gives context of its properties in the DB.